# How to define a state function for events

Tags: javascript

I would like to ask you for help because I can no longer work on JS because I don't understand what is being asked of me. Could you help me to define my reDisplay function? I have to call it (reDisplay) at the end of each "controller" function because it is this one that must work for the events and not the event functions.

The reDisplay function must redraw the rectangles according to the two variables that represent their state.  It must be called in my 3 click functions which are hooked to an event

I am stunned not to understand what is being asked of me because my JS level is not good. :(

The code is :

```
<body>
        <div class="rectContainer">
            <div class="rect red bigRect"></div>
            <div class="rect red bigRect"></div>
            <div class="rect red bigRect"></div>
        </div>
        <script>
            let rectAreBig = true; 
            console.log(rectAreBig);
            let stateRect1Color = "red"; 
            console.log(stateRect1Color);

            const rect1 = document.querySelector(".rect:nth-child(1)"); 
            rect1.addEventListener("click", () => {  
                switch (stateRect1Color) {
                    case "red":
                        stateRect1Color = "blue"; 
                        rect1.classList.remove("red"); 
                        rect1.classList.add("blue"); 
                        break;
                    case "blue":
                        stateRect1Color = "yellow"; 
                        rect1.classList.remove("blue"); 
                        rect1.classList.add("yellow"); 
                        break;
                    case "yellow":
                        stateRect1Color = "green"; 
                        rect1.classList.remove("yellow");
                        rect1.classList.add("green"); 
                        break;
                    case "green":
                        stateRect1Color = "red"; 
                        rect1.classList.remove("green"); 
                        rect1.classList.add("red"); 
                        break;
                    default: 
                        stateRect1Color = "red";
                }   
            });

            let rect2 = document.querySelector(".rectContainer :nth-child(2)"); 
            let allRects = document.querySelectorAll(".rect"); 

            rect2.addEventListener("click", () => {   
                if (rectAreBig) {
                   
                    for (let i = 0; i < allRects.length; i++) {
                       
                        allRects[i].classList.add("smallRect");
                        
                        rectAreBig = false;
                    } 
                } else {
                    
                    for (let i = 0; i < allRects.length; i++) {
                       
                        allRects[i].classList.remove("smallRect");
                        
                        rectAreBig = true; // comme dans les cours de algo
                    }
                }
            });

            const rect3 = document.querySelector(
                ".rectContainer :nth-child(3)"
            ); 
            rect3.addEventListener("click", () => {
                for (let i = 0; i < allRects.length; i++) {
                    allRects[i].classList.remove("smallRect", stateRect1Color);
                    allRects[0].classList.add("red");
                }  
            });

            
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I thank you in advance for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great opportunity to apply a mini Model View Controller (MVC) pattern.

- The **model** only contains the state
- The **view** only handles rendering.

  - Takes the model as its input.
- The **controller** handles logic/events, updates the model, and calls the view methods.

  - Takes both the view and model as inputs.

Having all 3 in one function is possible, but much harder to digest and navigate.

### Model

We have 3 rectangles, each with two state properties, `color` and `size`, so we can represent that as an array objects:

```
const model = [
  {color: 'red', size: 'big'},
  {color: 'red', size: 'big'},
  {color: 'red', size: 'big'}
]
```

### View

The view takes our model as input, and manipulates the DOM accordig to it. We can implement its methods in many ways such as re-rendering the elements each time, or updating specific class names, etc. For this, we can keep it simple and have it clear and re-render each time based.

**All** DOM related functions are put in the view.

```
function view(model) {
  const container = document.querySelector('.rectContainer');
  const rectElements = {}
  
  function createRectHTML(rect) {
    return `<div class="rect ${rect.color} ${rect.size}"></div>`
  }

  function render() {
    const HTMLArray = model.map(rectObj => createRectHTML(rectObj));
    const elementHTML = HTMLArray.join('');
    container.innerHTML = '';
    container.innerHTML = elementHTML;

    rectElements.one = container.children[0];
    rectElements.two = container.children[1];
    rectElements.three = container.children[2];
  }
  
  return {render, rectElements}
}
```

### Controller

The controller will take our model instance, and view function, it will then pass the model into the view function to make a view instance. It sets the listeners and contains the handlers that will manipulate the model and call the view methods.

```
function controller(model, viewFunction) {
  const view = viewFunction(model);
  let rectAreBig = true;
  
  function update() {
    view.render();
    setListeners();
  }
  
  update();
  
  function changeColor(){
    const color = model[0].color;
    const newColor = color === 'red'? 'blue'
      : color === 'blue' ? 'yellow'
      : color === 'yellow' ? 'green'
      : 'red'
    model[0].color = newColor;
    update();
    }

  function changeSize(){
    const newSize = rectAreBig ? 'small' : 'big';
    rectAreBig = !rectAreBig;
    model.forEach(rect => rect.size = newSize);
    update();
  }

  function reset() {
    model.forEach(rect => {
      rect.size = 'big';
      rect.color = 'red';
    })
    rectAreBig = true;
    update();
  }

  function setListeners() {
    view.rectElements.one.onclick = () => changeColor();
    view.rectElements.two.onclick = () => changeSize();
    view.rectElements.three.onclick = () => reset();
  }
}
```

### Putting it all together:

```js
const model = [
  {color: 'red', size: 'big'},
  {color: 'red', size: 'big'},
  {color: 'red', size: 'big'}
]

function view(model) {
  const container = document.querySelector('.rectContainer');
  const rectElements = {}
  
  function createRectHTML(rect) {
    return `<div class="rect ${rect.color} ${rect.size}"></div>`
  }

  function render() {
    const HTMLArray = model.map(rectObj => createRectHTML(rectObj));
    const elementHTML = HTMLArray.join('');
    container.innerHTML = '';
    container.innerHTML = elementHTML;

    rectElements.one = container.children[0];
    rectElements.two = container.children[1];
    rectElements.three = container.children[2];
  }
  
  return {render, rectElements}
}

function controller(model, viewFunction) {
  const view = viewFunction(model);
  let rectAreBig = true;
  
  function update() {
    view.render();
    setListeners();
  }
  
  update();
  
  function changeColor(){
    const color = model[0].color;
    const newColor = color === 'red'? 'blue'
      : color === 'blue' ? 'yellow'
      : color === 'yellow' ? 'green'
      : 'red'
    model[0].color = newColor;
    update();
    }

  function changeSize(){
    const newSize = rectAreBig ? 'small' : 'big';
    rectAreBig = !rectAreBig;
    model.forEach(rect => rect.size = newSize);
    update();
  }

  function reset() {
    model.forEach(rect => {
      rect.size = 'big';
      rect.color = 'red';
    })
    rectAreBig = true;
    update();
  }

  function setListeners() {
    view.rectElements.one.onclick = () => changeColor();
    view.rectElements.two.onclick = () => changeSize();
    view.rectElements.three.onclick = () => reset();
  }
}

controller(model, view)
```

```css
.rectContainer{
   display: flex;
   gap: 20px;
}

.rect.big{
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
}

.rect.small{
   width: 70px;
   height: 70px;
}

.rect.red{
   background-color: red;
}

.rect.blue{
   background-color: blue;
}

.rect.green{
   background-color: green;
}

.rect.yellow{
   background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="rectContainer"></div>
```